# Playing IceCast2 stream in html

Tags: html, icecast, m3u

So i can play the stream with **Vlc media player .m3u**.

**.m3u:**
http://IP:8000/source

But i cant play it with a browser.

Can you help me?

**And im now streaming to the server with obs, im recording a video on it**

Comment: What does the web interface at http://IP:8000/ tell you about the stream? What format/codecs/etc?

Comment: Content Type: video/m2ts

Comment: I don't think any browsers will support m2ts (That's MPEG2-TransportStream). You'll probably fare much better using WebM with Opus for Audio and VP9 or AV1 for video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can play back many streams that are broadcast through Icecast.
However you don't want to point your player at the `m3u` file, but *directly* at the stream URL instead.

There are:

- "HTML5" players that use the the `<audio>` or `<video>` tags
- JavaScript based abstractions on top of the aforementioned
- JavaScript 'compiled' players that bring their own decoders and such for browsers that don't support things natively

For the [Audio-element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_audio#Supported_audio_coding_formats) there are a few supported formats and I personally use Opus in Ogg.

For the [Video-element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_audio#Supported_audio_coding_formats) there are a few supported formats and I personally use Opus + AV1 or Opus + VP9 inside WebM.

Please note that the "container" (WebM, Ogg, MP4, etc.) is relevant, not just the choice of the codec. Especially for web browsers as they tend to support a much smaller subset than dedicated media players.

In "the olden days" there were also Adobe Flash and Java-applet based players, but they really are irrelevant by now.

When it comes to formats, I'd recommend the Opus codec as it is supported by most browser engines nowadays. For some use cases MP3 might be valid and while proprietary is nowadays no longer patent encumbered. AAC might bring licensing requirements for encoders etc. along.

Comment: Thanks, but now i have a another problem. We're streaming with FFempeg. Can we display it somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you explain a bit more.

Comment: im going to update the question